# XNA: "TextureCoordinate0" missing, but I'm not using textures

Tags: xna, 3d, textures

I'm trying to create a voxel game using XNA, but I'm getting a somewhat bizarre error when calling `DrawIndexedPrimitives()`:

```
InvalidOperationException was unhandled
The current vertex declaration does not include all the elements required by the
current vertex shader. TextureCoordinate0 is missing.
```

Which makes *some* sense, as it's true my vertex data structure (`VertexPositionColorNormal` as shown in [this Riemers tutorial](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/Lighting_basics.php)) does not contain texture data.

However, the effect *shouldn't* require texture data - I made it a point to set `drawingEngine.TextureEnabled = false;` in my graphics setup method.  So why is this exception being thrown?  And what can I do about it?

For some context, here's my draw method:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch drawer)
{
    drawingEngine.View = player.createViewMatrix();

    Vector3 direction = player.getDirection();

    for (int x = 0; x < mapSize; x++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < mapSize; z++)
        {
            Chunk drawee = map.get(new IntVector3(x, mapCenter, z));
            if (drawee == null)
                continue;
            if(drawee.isTransparent())
                continue;
            #region chunkdrawer

            DynamicVertexBuffer vertexBuffer = drawee.getVertexBuffer();
            int numVertices = drawee.getNumVertices();
            DynamicIndexBuffer indexBuffer = drawee.getIndexBuffer();
            int numIndices = drawee.getNumIndices();

            graphics.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);
            graphics.Indices = indexBuffer;

            foreach (EffectPass p in drawingEngine.CurrentTechnique.Passes)  //Not sure I entirely understand this
            {
                graphics.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, numVertices, 0, numIndices / 3);
            }
            #endregion chunkdrawer
        }
    }
    drawer.End();
    drawer.Begin();
}
```

And here is the graphics setup method:

```
void graphicsNonsense()
{
    drawingEngine = new BasicEffect(graphics);

    drawingEngine.World = world;
    drawingEngine.Projection = projection;


    drawingEngine.TextureEnabled = false;
    drawingEngine.VertexColorEnabled = true;

    drawingEngine.EnableDefaultLighting();
    drawingEngine.SpecularColor= new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Try to enable VertexColors in the drawingEngine structure like you disabled textures, see if it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I did that, no change :(

Comment: It's probably worth noting that I also tried putting those two statements into the foreach effectpass loop, which also yielded no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling p.Apply() in your drawing code to set the effect correctly on the GPU before drawing.

```
foreach (EffectPass p in drawingEngine.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
    p.Apply(); // this will set the effect
    graphics.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, numVertices, 0, numIndices / 3);
}
```